# Initializing multiple subclassed sprites of the same kind in Cocos2D from Tiled

Tags: initialization, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to figure out the best way to initialize multiple sprites placed in Tiled that are the same type. I don't even know really how to start off in Tiled, because I'm only used to initializing one sprite by filling out the name field, and then in my CCLayer with the map I do something like

```
CCTMXObjectGroup *objects = [theMap objectGroupNamed:@"oj"];
NSMutableDictionary *startPoint = [objects objectNamed:@"StartPoint"];
int x = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
int y = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];

hero = [[HeroClass alloc] init];

[self addChild:hero.heroSpriteSheet];

hero.heroSprite.position = ccp(x,y);
```

As you can see, my "hero" is subclassed, and this goes for another sprite that is a bird, but I want an x amount of them. I import the header of HeroClass and create a pointer, make a property and synthesize that in my main file and finally release HeroClass in dealloc. I have a feeling that I will most likely end up use NSMutableArray, but I don't really know how in the case of subclassing. Also I'm not sure if I'll be using objectNamed:@"name" because I'll have x number of these sprites that I will be just duplicating throughout Tiled.

There's a helpful post here that shows how to add multiple sprites, but I don't know how to relate it to Tiled or subclassing:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/58334-adding-sprites-screen-when-detecting-tap-cocos2d.html

Does anyone have any useful pointers or code examples relating how to resolve my issue? Thanks!

**TLDR:**

How do I initialize sprites from the same class in a CCLayer (that renders my map and other sprites) based upon definite object locations that were placed in a Tiled TMX map?

Comment: Hey, welcome, feel free to choose a username and stay awhile. :-)

Comment: Do you mean that you want multiple instances of a character created?

Comment: Yes, like say if it was an enemy and you would see 5 on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggesting creating an enemy class. Then, you create a bunch of them using a for loop. As far as spawnpoints, you would have each enemy set its own spawn point up based on rules. (Map borders, "safe areas", etc.)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but yes it is a class, it would obviously be some kind of loop, and I don't want "spawnpoints" based on rules.  I want definite locations based on objects placed in Tiled. Not quite sure you why you mentioned that.

Comment: Ok, so what's the question, in a line?

Comment: How do I initialize x number of sprites from the same class in a CCLayer (that renders my map and other sprites) based upon definite object locations that were placed in a Tiled TMX map?